# Debugging ArcPy ERROR 000358: Invalid expression?

Tags: arcpy, sql, select-by-attribute, error-000358

I've tried several iterations of this SQL statement in a stand alone script:

```
    QF5 = "Week"
    QF6 = "Wk"
    RV3 = ""
    WC4 = """" {} <> {} AND {} <> '{}' """.format(QF5,QF6,QF6, RV3)
```

I'm aiming for an expression that would read int he field calculator:

```
Select From(*) Table Where:
Week <> Wk AND Wk <> ''
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute)
```

Comment: Your SQL is not correct: Select * From [Table] Where
Week <> Wk AND Wk <> ''

Comment: Right, sorry I was just guessing the first part of the query from the field calculator. That bit is not being expressed int the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work: `WC4 = """{0} <> {1} AND {1} <> ''""".format(QF5,QF6)`
Your double quotes were unbalanced, and you don't need `RV3`.